# How to get font I got from dafont.com to work in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I downloaded it from dafont.com but I used this generator from fontsquirrel.com and put in it my css:

```
`@font-face {
  font-family: "victor_monoregular";
  src: url("victormono-regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("victormono-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
`
```

It's not working on different browsers though.

I tried putting

```
`"src: url(VictorMono.otf);"`
```

in my css file.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer like the actual css rules applying the font to your elements. E.g `body{font-family: "victor_monoregular"}` Check your devtools network tab if fonts are actually loaded. If not there is probably something wrong with your file paths/URLs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.